# Mysql how to make row null when duplicated in join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here is the table. As you can see the post_likes are being duplicated:

[image: Picture 1]

Here is what I want to make null because the likes are being duplicated:

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: It can be done using user variables like this: http://rextester.com/FVMR97502  and specific order by's ***I don't recommend it*** This type of action is best suited in the presentation layer;  as @darshanMehta mentioned this is the way joins are suppose to  work.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how `JOIN` works in SQL. If you have `m`, `n` and `o` records in 3 tables respectively, `JOINING` them will result in `m x n x o` records. If you don't want duplicate values in `likes` and/or `comments` then you can fetch them separately, with two different `JOIN` queries.